# Building Portaudio in C on Sublime Text 3

Tags: c, makefile, build, portaudio

I'm attempting to build an example code from portaudio using the library from this page. https://github.com/adfernandes/precompiled-portaudio-windows

My sublime-build file is the following:

```
{
    "cmd" : ["gcc", "$file_name", "-L/Desktop/portaudio-r1891-build/lib/x64/ReleaseMinDependency", "-llibportaudio_x64", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "&&", "${file_base_name}.exe"],
    "selector" : "source.c",
    "shell" : true,
    "working_dir" : "$file_path"
}
```

I receive the error "c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -llibportaudio_x64

I'm new to make files so am unsure what's incorrect. Without the portaudio additions, the make file properly builds a Hello World test code. The portaudio stuff is not in a standard path. I have "#include "portaudio.h" in the portaudio example code and the .h file in the same folder as the example code. I have the folder of the libraries on my desktop and am attempting to link it's path to that folder with the -L command. I've seen some people discussing about having a .a file but I don't seem to have one from the library downloaded.

Comment: Does adding `"-m64"` after `"gcc"` fix it?

Comment: I suspect this syntax may cause problem `-llibportaudio_x64`. Try `-lportaudio_x64` instead.

Comment: @a3f doing this gave the error "paex_sine.c:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in /**@file paex_sine.c"

Comment: @user3078414 I tried it without the "lib" and received the same error but with "-lportaudio_x64"

Answer (score 0):

You are linking your 32-bit program against the 64 bit version of the DLL.

Either change the Link path (`-L`) to the 32-bit DLL's location or use a 64-bit compiler.

At first I suspected it's the missing `lib` prefix, but the MinGW documentation says that the `lib` can be omitted on Windows.